# How to set the li style?

Tags: html, css

usually I use li to do this:

```
<ol class="d">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Coca Cola</li>
</ol>
```

and I style set to this:

```
ol.d {list-style-type:lower-alpha;}
```

and the result like this:

```
a. Coffee
b. Tea
c. Coca Cola
```

But I would like to modify in order to make the result like this:

```
(a) Coffee
(b) Tea
(c) Coca Cola
```

How can I do so? Thank you.

Comment: To mark an answer to a question as accepted, click on the checkmark at the left. You can only do this for one answer per question. Remember to do the same for all your previously-answered questions. It's a way of thanking us!

Answer (score 14):

Well you can use the `counter`-related properties, but they're not well-supported in some browsers (like old versions of IE).

```css
ol.d {
    counter-reset: item;
}

ol.d li:before {
    content: '(' counter(item, lower-alpha) ') ';
    counter-increment: item;
}
```

Some references:

- [jsFiddle preview](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/N8ECA) of above code
- [W3C spec on automatic numbering](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#counters)
- [SitePoint Reference on CSS generated content](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/generatedcontent)

Comment: +1 That's pretty neat!  Do you have a recommended link where I could read up on them?

Comment: [Here is a good link](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/counter.html) about the CSS counter feature.

Comment: @Steve: Just added some links.

Comment: That doesn’t quite look like a list, since the generated content is left-aligned. You might be able to use positioning to work around this. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N8ECA/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify how the list items appear other than using a list image. IF you want to do this you'll have to simulate it with extra markup and margin/positioning trickery.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it's not set in the default CSS for `list-style-type`.  You can refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/list-style-type for what's available via CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
ol { counter-reset: item }
li:before { content: "( " counter(item, upper-latin) " ) "; counter-increment: item }
```