# Make `(1)` in list style

Tags: html, css

I want to make the following using `list` in HTML

```
The following are the properties:
  (1) blah blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah
      blahblahblahblah
  (2) blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah
      blahblahblahblah
```

If I use `list-style-type` as decimal, I will get like

```
The following are the properties:
  1. blah blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah
     blahblahblahblah
  2. blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah
     blahblahblahblah
```

Can I achieve the former using `list` or by any other means?

**Edit:**

On using Boltclock's answer to [How to set the li style??](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644469/how-to-set-the-li-style) I used:

```
ol.d {
    counter-reset: item;
}

ol.d li:before {
    content: '(' counter(item) ') ';
    counter-increment: item;
}

<ol class="d">
  <li>blah blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah
      blahblahblahblah</li>
  <li>blah blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah
      blahblahblahblah</li>
</ol>
```

I get the result like this:

```
The following are the properties:
  (1) blah blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah
  blahblahblahblah
  (2) blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah
  blahblahblahblah
```

Now I'd like to indent the second line also. How can I achieve this?

Comment: A nearly-identical question can be found here: [How to set the li style??](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644469/how-to-set-the-li-style) I don't think I should be reposting the same answer since I've already answered that one with a solution equally applicable to yours...

Comment: @boltclock..I have edited my question..can u look into it?

Comment: I'll see what I can come up with.

Comment: @BoltClock: I reopened this in light of the follow-up question.  Thanks for flagging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with a workaround using floats, but it's **extremely fragile** and relies on the actual number of list items you will have. The more digits of numbers, the more you need to increase your margins to account for it. Not to mention it depends on what font you use too.

```
ol.d {
    counter-reset: item;
}

ol.d li {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 1.5em;
}

ol.d li:before {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: -1.5em;
    content: '(' counter(item) ') ';
    counter-increment: item;
}
```

Be sure to clear the floats with whatever element follows your `ol`.

[jsFiddle preview](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/bmkjd)

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: My answer addresses the follow-up question about generated content inlining with the content, which can normally be worked around by using `list-style-position: outside` but not in this case.

Comment: @BoltClock I’m aware of this. Just try out your code in jsFiddle with floating removed – it still works: http://jsfiddle.net/bmkjd/4/

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: Once you increase the magnitude of the margins, there'll be a difference between floating and not floating. Compare http://jsfiddle.net/bmkjd/5 and http://jsfiddle.net/bmkjd/6

Comment: @BoltClock Drat, what a coincidence. It only really works at 1.5em. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
Use below css for (1) style in ol listing


ol {
counter-reset: item;
list-style-type: none;
}

ol li{position: relative;}

ol li:before {
position: absolute;  
   margin: 0px 0 0 -25px;    
   vertical-align: middle;
   display: inline-block;
   content: '(' counter(item, decimal) ' ) ';
   counter-increment: item;
}
```